Confluent JDBC source connector issue with table whitelist option
We are using Confluent Kafka JDBC source connector to fetch data from AWS RDS(Oracle db).The connector is working for select * from table name but it does not work with table whitelist option.It is hitting the below exception TableMonitorThread exception.
Error: Encountered an unrecoverable error while reading tables from the database.
We are using the Oracle 19c db but ojdbc8 driver. I referred the documentation.it supports. Able to get the data via query mode.
The table whitelist option works with MySQL database and for fetching multiples table to each Kafka topics using Single source connector configs in my personal laptop. Unfortunately I could paste the complete configs list due to I am working in client machine.

I found the problem. When I gave the schema.pattern value,it worked with table.whitelist for Oracle table.This schema.pattern is not required for MySQL DB when I tested.
